# Executing rsync shell command from php file on web browser

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, php, rsync

Firstly, we wanna move the changes from one system to another system and for this, we have a shell script in `synchfolders.sh` file as follows

```
rsync -av --delete -e 'sshpass -p Wordpress@123 ssh -p 22' root@192.168.2.94:/var/www/html/prosync/wp-content/plugins/ /var/www/html/devsync/wp-content/plugins >> /var/www/html/devsync/wp-content/mysynclog.txt
```

and we want to execute this shell script in PHP file by `shell_exec()` and while executing this PHP file from a browser other than rsync command, all are executing but the `rsync` is not executing. We have searched the stuff in SO and we got the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772816/php-exec-rsync-ssh-to-remote-server-not-working/30773063#30773063, as said here we have tried the PHP file execution from the command line and works perfect but not through the browser. Why, Please let us know where we did a mistake. Thanks in advance

Comment: Start by piping stdout and stderr into files and review those files after a run - most likely you'll see the reason there.

Comment: how can we add the stdout and stderr in file, will you provide us an example

Answer (score 2):

In general: in scripts that don't get executed from  your usual interactive shell you need to ensure that you either **use absolute paths** (i.e. `/usr/bin/rsync` instead of `rsync`)  or **set up the correct environment** with a good value for $PATH

---

As an additional improvement: rather than password based authentication you should really set up key based ssh authentication  for use in scripts.

When you stop using passwords and start using keys you can lock down and secure the ssh server (disabling password authentication will stop brute force attacks) and more importantly you can add restrictions to what is allowed when a particular key is used for authentication, which is something you can't do with a password.

You can restrict the key used in your script so it can only be used for rsync from a specific host.

Then even if your script is compromised it won't be your root password (which grants full control to your server) that is stolen, but only a private key that grants limited access, if it can be used at all.